# Why does casting float64 to int32 give a negative number in Go?

Tags: c++, go, floating-point, ieee-754

Occasionally, we cast `float64` to `int32` directly by mistake in Golang

```golang
    raw = 529538871408
    fv = float64(raw)

    fmt.Println(raw)
    fmt.Println(fv)
    fmt.Println(int32(fv))
```

Output

```
529538871408
5.29538871408e+11
-2147483648
```

Why `int32(fv)` given a negative number?

As we know, both `long` in C++ and `float64` in Golang is a 64 bit IEEE 754 double precision. So we try same code in C++

```c
    int64_t iv = 529538871408;
    std::cout << iv << std::endl;

    double fv = double(iv);
    std::cout << fv << std::endl;

    int32_t i32v = int32_t(fv);
    std::cout << i32v << std::endl;
```

Output:

```
529538871408
5.29539e+11
2147483647
```

The result is `2147483647`, why? Is anything am I missing? or something wrong?

Comment: I have no knowledge about `golang` but `int32` implies a number in the range `[-2147483648, 2147483647]` (two's compliment). 529538871408 > 2^31 so, overflow. Signed overflows may be ok in `golang` but they are not in C++ (until C++20).

Comment: "Why int32(fv) given a negative number?" Because the language spec says it must.

Comment: You're doing something unspecified in Go: ["In all non-constant conversions involving floating-point or complex values, if the result type cannot represent the value the conversion succeeds but the result value is implementation-dependent."](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Conversions)

Comment: @Volker, could you please me the link of the language spec?

Answer (score 3):

In go you can overflow to the sign bit

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    a, b := int32(2147483647), int32(1)
    c := a + b
    fmt.Printf("%d %T", c, c)
}
```

[check it out on playground](https://play.golang.org/p/Q5D5Umt8s2s)

Answer (score 0):

What is your OS and compiler? I'm using gcc version 10.3.0 (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1~20.10) and the result is also negative.

Back to the topic, overflow behavior is usually undefined behavior in most programming languages, and different compiler implementations of the same language may have different effects.

```cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int64_t iv = 529538871408;
    std::cout << iv << std::endl;

    double fv = double(iv);
    std::cout << fv << std::endl;

    int32_t i32v = int32_t(fv);
    std::cout << i32v << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
/*
Output
529538871408
5.29539e+11
-2147483648
/*
```